# Retrieve information from URL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, url

Suppose I have an url like:

http://localhost:1122/MyProject/MyPage.aspx?from=home&id=454.

I can retrieve the 'form' value in code behind like Request["from"]. How can I do the same using JavaScript? Can I do this using jQuery also?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You don't need jQuery, just pure JavaScript. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery/901144#901144).